# Error: "Session/EntityManager is closed" when using SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am updating my spring boot project from version 2.5.4 to version 2.6.2, which means spring-boot-starter-jdbc updates as well.

Now I have this code using `SessionFactory` that worked in spring boot 2.5.4 but doesn't work on version 2.6.2 and throws `Session/EntityManager is closed` error.

**GenericHibernateDao.java:**

```java
public abstract class GenericHibernateDao implements GenericDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Session getCurrentSession() { return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); }
}
```

**EmployeeDAOImpl.java:**

```java
public class EmployeeDAOImpl extends GenericHibernateDao {

    public Employee getEmployeeByName(String name) {
        Query namedQuery = getCurrentSession.getNamedQuery("getEmployeeByName");
        namedQuery.setParameter("name", name);
        return (Employee) namedQuery.uniqueResult();
    }
}
```

The error accures when trying to execute `return (Employee) namedQuery.uniqueResult();` line.

The `getEmployeeByName` method is called from `@PostConstruct` of another component.
I don't understand why the error accures, and what is the difference between the versions?
Any help will be appriciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the exception was a property in hibernateProperties.
after I deleted the next line everything runs as it should:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</property>
```

It seems to be ok because we use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.

The error look like a bug in hibernate [link to open bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11311?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel)